# BlueZone Object Method "SendKeys"

Tags: python, mainframe, bluezone

I am using BlueZone Script Host to automate repetitive mainframe tasks and I am trying to use Sendkeys method to pass in Shift F6. The documentation on IBM's website says .  Not sure why only my PF6 is working but not shift. Any ideas?

https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/bluezone/help/v51/en/bzsh/APPENDIX/IBM_Send_Key_Table.htm

code:

```
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    bzo = win32com.client.Dispatch("BZWhll.WhllObj")
    bzo.Connect('')
    
    for x in range(9, 20):
        a = bzo.ReadScreen('buff', '10', x, 7)
        excr_amt = Decimal(a[1].strip().replace(",",""))

        if len(str(excr_amt)) == 5:
            bzo.PSCursorPos = pos - 9
            bzo.SendKeys("x")
            bzo.Wait(2)
            bzo.SendKeys("<shifton><PF6>")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try sending PF18, that should be equivalent to shift-PF6.

Comment: I'm still trying to think of a usecase for `<ShiftOn>` - `SendKeys("<ShiftOn>d")` will result in `d`, for uppercase I need to do `SendKeys("D")`. So any idea what it could be needed for?

Comment: I think `<ShiftOn>` might be there for cases where program interprets key combinations. Like open window X if key-down shift is received 3 times in a row. But in the context of `SendKeys("<ShiftOn>d")` that's 1- send shift key-down 2- send lower case d.